# Shopware6 cannot disable PayPal Ratepay Banner (auto-reenabled after page reload)

Tags: paypal, shopware6, paypal-plus

In Shopware 6, the PayPal Ratepay Banner (PayPal Pay Later Message) is enabled by default. Theoretically the banner should be possible to disable in Settings > Addons > PayPal. But after clicking the corresponding button, saving and reloading the page the button is enabled again.

---

Shopware Version: v6.4.7.0 stable

Paypal Version: 4.1.0

Language: German

Answer (score 0):

- Please make sure you flushed the caches after changing the setting
- If you have multiple storefronts, make sure it is disabled for the current store view